# Can you make Windows treat an external display exactly like an internal one?

Tags: windows-7, display, .net-framework, external-display

I have Windows 7 Home 64-bit and a monitor attached to my desktop over DVI. Is there any way to make the system think that there is no external display attached or to make it think that the display attached is an integrated display?

For example, if someone would ask the .NET Screen class (or whichever one is responsible for this, I forget) to enumerate all of the screens it would report an integrated display.

Comment: For what purpose do you want this?

Comment: There's a program I want to use that checks if there is a display other than an integrated monitor attached, and doesn't allow you to use the program if there is one.

Comment: Its a hardware level restriction, since it is connected to an External display port, unless of course you are adept at hacking the video driver at the hardware level, or better yet modify the bios file before you flash it. Even then I am not sure it is possible to get the outcome you wish.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you are right. If you put that in an answer I'll give it to you unless someone else comes up with something else.